# Calling a rakefile from NAnt

Tags: ruby, rake, nant

I am dealing with a relatively large project, and up until this point building has been done in a NAnt build script. Recently a small portion of development was done in ruby, and is built using a rake file.  I would like to create a NAnt target that will call the rakefile.  Current set-up in the NAnt build: (Note that the rakefile is in a different directory from the NAnt script)

```
<property overwrite="false" name="project.rootdirectory" value="${project::get-base-directory()}" />
<property overwrite="false" name="rake.exe" value="rake.bat" />

<target name="callrake">
    <exec program="${rake.exe}" verbose="true">
        <arg value="build:foo" />
        <arg line="-f ${project.rootdirectory}/../pathtorakefile" />
    </exec>
</target>
```

The error that I recieve when I run `nant callrake` is:

```
[exec] ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- c:/pathtoNAntscript/rake (LoadError)
c:/pathtoNAntscript/NAntscript.build 
External Program Failed: rake.bat (return code was 1)
```

Ruby and rake are installed, and the Ruby bin is in the path variable.  Not sure why NAnt cant seem to call rake.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is solved by calling cmd.exe and passing it the rake command as text:

```
<exec program="cmd.exe" verbose="true">
    <arg line="/c ${rake.exe} build:foo" />
    <arg line="-f ${project.rootdirectory}/../pathtorakefile/Rakefile.rb" />
</exec>
```